# How to find results between three collections in mongo using id

Tags: mongodb

I have three collections.

users collection:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58a0506767535d5cehjk678"),
  "name" : "someUser",
  "username" : "someUserName"
}
```

training:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5hkhgec28863b500045ff0d6"),
  "location" : "somePlace",
  "coacherId" : "58b9edca8863b500045ff0d0", // userId
  "maxParticipants" : NumberInt(10),
  "time" : ISODate("2017-03-05T17:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

userOrders:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("591iuyt602d3ec00049b7c93"),
  "userId" : "5hkhgec28863b500045ff0d6",
  "trainingId" : "5hkhgec28863b500045ff0d6"
}
```

how can i find the all training of specific user between two dates?
there is some thing for it in mongo, of only by 3 queries?

Comment: Why do you need the third collection, you could just add a training id in the user collection, or an array of user information in the training collection.

Comment: because i need more details about any order, such as start date and and date.

Answer (score 0):

It might be achievable using MongoDB's Aggregation capabilities and with the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation stage.

Something like this:

```
db.userOrders.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                "userId" : ObjectId("597c95e3acc4ed0de91a2992") // the id of the user
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                "from" : "training",
                "localField" : "trainingId",
                "foreignField" : "_id",
                "as" : "training"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$training"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "training.time" : { $gte: ISODate("2017-03-05T00:00:00.0Z"), $lt: ISODate("2017-03-08T00:00:00.0Z") }
            }
        },
        // if you use MongoDB version >= 3.4
        {
            $replaceRoot: {
                newRoot: "$training"
        }
    }
    ]
);
```

Example output document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("597c9608acc4ed0de91a2995"), 
    "location" : "somePlace", 
    "coacherId" : "\"Joe\"", 
    "maxParticipants" : NumberInt(10), 
    "time" : ISODate("2017-03-05T17:00:00.000+0000")
}
```